# Parsing csv-like input (with a little quirk)

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I'm working on a little Android app to bleep whenever I get to pause or I have to start running again.
It's very basic: I only have made an input validator using regex and now I'm trying to parse that input.

The input is like a csv, but I want to have repeating groups.

E.g.: `2.5,1,5(6,3),1,2.5`  means 2.5 mins of warming up, 1 min walking and then five times six mins of running and 3 mins walking... (You get the rest I hope)

The main problem is that splitting the string on commas means that the repeating group gets split as well. I could possibly use another delimiter inside those groups, but that doesn't seem as neat to me :)

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks,

Antarion

(btw: this is my regex https://regex101.com/r/kJ3rP8/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your question is:**

How to split a string by comma unless it is inside brackets.

**The regex you need is:**

```
,(?=[^\)]*(?:\(|$))
```

**What it does:**

`,` -> split string by comma

`(?=` -> begginning of 'lookahead'. This means: split only if the *following* characters are like so:

`[^\)]` -> NOT closing brackets

`*` -> repeated 0 or more times

`(?:` -> not capturing lookahead

`\(` -> closing brackets

`|` -> or

`$` -> end of string

Comment: Won't work with nested groupings, but if that's not a requirement, should be good enough

Comment: It isn't :) 
Thank you verrry much!

Answer (score 0):

Regex isn't really the right tool to handle parsing that requires state. You are better off just parsing it imperatively. Something like this, perhaps:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+?)([,()])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while(m.find) {
   String number = m.group(1);
   String delim  = m.group(2);
   if(delim.equals("(")) startRepeatingGroup(number);
   else if(delim.equals(")")  endRepeatingGroup(number);
   else processNextNumber(number) 
}
```

Comment: How does that code work? How would you code the other functions?